# How to import global SCSS file in a React/Redux project?

Tags: sass, webpack, react-redux

I'm using [`react-redux-starter-kit`](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit) for my project. I want to know how it is possible to create a global SCSS file that when imported in [`_base.scss`](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit/blob/master/src/styles/_base.scss), it will affect the whole project. I've tried to `@import` like in the examples within the file, but nothing works. Strangely, it seems to have worked with `@import './fonts/*'`;

I have the following structure:

> `styles/
>   ----/components/
>   --------/Dashboard
>   --------/Home
>   --------_default.scss
>   ----/fonts/
>   ----_base.scss
>   ----core.scss`

And therefore, the `_base.scss` is like this:

`@import './components/_default'`

But it doesn't work. No errors are shown. I've tried also to create a `theme/default.scss`, just like the example in the commentary within the file, but also no effect.

Answer (score 0):

In your root component just import your main `scss` file like you would import a module:

```
require('path/to/styles/_base.scss')
```

or:

```
import 'path/to/styles/_base.scss'
```

Just make sure that in your **webpack config** there is:

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loader: 'style!css!sass',
}
```